# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - Python 3.5

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a small code in Python, which looks like that:

```
import sys
def _158a():
    n, k = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    data = input().split()
    a=[]
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(int(data[i]))
    ans=0
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i]>=a[k-1] and a[i]:
            ans+=1
    return ans

res = _158a()
print(res)
```

with input from keyboard:

```
3 3
1 2 3
```

When i run code with above input, i got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tranhieu/Desktop/Python/158A.py", line 14, in <module>
    res = _158a()
  File "/Users/tranhieu/Desktop/Python/158A.py", line 4, in _158a
    data = input().split()
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you help me fix this bug?

Comment: It works for me. I can't reproduce this.

Comment: You aren't using Python 3, you're using Python 2, where `input` runs `eval`.

Comment: Try adding `print(sys.version_info)` before that line, and let us know what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, since in Python 2.x `input()` tries to parse the input. In Python 3.x `input()` just returns a string like `raw_input()` in Python 2.x.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake. I run my code in Python 2.7.1. It works in Python 3.5.