# Python 3.5: Invalid syntax with split('/').[-1]

Tags: python, python-3.5

In a virtual env, I am using python 3.5.2. When I run

python file.py . I get below error

```
filename = source_path.split('/').[-1]
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For the code snippet

```
for line in lines:
    source_path = line[0]
    filename = source_path.split('/').[-1]
```

I saw similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187161/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-python-3-5) where the OP got error as he was using python 2.7. But I am using 3.5.2 in my virtual environment. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean `source_path.split('/')[-1]`? No need for the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `.` before `[]`

```
filename = source_path.split('/')[-1]
#                               ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

`source_path.split('/')` will return a `list`, and to access the index of the list you need to do

```
filename = source_path.split('/')[-1]
```